# Depending on the INSTALL target of a CMake External Project

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there a way to identify dependencies of the installation-step of a target in *cmake*?  Here's my situation:

My goal is to be able to download the source code of this project and build it without first installing the dependencies.  In other words, I'd like the dependencies to be recognized and installed prior to trying to build the main target.  For example, I'm working on including Leptonica as an external project:

```
set(leptonica_build "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/leptonica")

ExternalProject_Add(
    leptonica
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${download_dir}
    BINARY_DIR ${leptonica_build}
    GIT_REPOSITORY ${OpenCV_git_repository}
    GIT_TAG ${OpenCV_git_tag}
    TLS_VERIFY true
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix=${DOC_READER_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

Running the target **leptonica** correctly builds and installs the library into a temporary directory, making itself available to other targets to consume:

```
add_dependencies(myProgram leptonica)
find_library(LEPT_LIB lept)
target_link_libraries(myProgram ${LEPT_LIB})
```

The problem is that, when */tmp* is cleared and *cmake* is first executed with the target of *myProgram*, *liblept.so* isn't found because it hasn't yet been installed, and consequently an upstream dependency of *myProgram* hasn't been met until **after** *make install* has been run.

In other words, I'd like the build script to first download and install then dependencies, then try to lookup the location of the libraries needed by downstream build steps.  Is this possible to do with *cmake* or should I be accomplishing this goal some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build and install `leptonica` from a separate `CMakeLists.txt`. Alternatively, you can use the same `CMakeLists` and selectively enable either the `ExternalProject`-section or the main section of your `CMakeLists` with a control variable (`-DMYPROJECT_INSTALL_DEPS=1`)

You can trigger the configure/build steps of `leptonica` from shell script, or call `cmake` from the main `CMakeLists` with `execute_process`:

```
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -H... -B...
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ... --target install ...
    )
```

That way the entire configuration/build/install steps will get executed in the configuration step of your main project.

Comment: Thank you, that's the strategy I'm working with now.

Comment: Could you please explain what `-H` and `-B` means and why they are need to be used together for that purpose ? I don't see them on the documentation

Comment: @LewisChan `-B` is documented (path to binary dir), `-H` (path to source dir) is an undocumented switch, now they've made it official under `-S`.